# How to color one cell in my formattable in R

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to create a table in R with formattable. I can have already used formattable to create a table where the color depended on the values. But there is one cell that I just want to be red, no matter what is in the cell, and I can't figure out how to do this.

```
result_table <- cbind(Normal = c(1,2,3), Fraud = c(4,5,6))
row.names(result_table) <- c('Normal', "Suspicious", "Fraud")
my_df <- as.data.frame(result_table)
formattable(my_df)
```

I want to color normal vs normal green, fraud vs fraud green, normal vs fraud red, fraud vs normal red. But since I'm using formattable also for the other tables in my report, I'd like to use it here as well (so that all tables in my report have the same style.)

Comment: Works for me. Seriously, though, you need to tell us what your data is, what you did, what was the output. Did you read [this intro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html)?

Comment: Almost there, just correct the `result_table` to `my_results`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the problem, the problem is that I want to color some cells green, and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is *a* solution, although not a perfect one. First, we define the formatters – functions that take the data and turn it into HTML code:

```
red.f <- formatter("span", style=x~style(color="red"))
green.f <- formatter("span", style=x~style(color="green"))
```

It is possible to make these functions conditional, but unfortunately neither is formatter well documented nor the authors foresaw your problem.

Now then.

```
my_df2 <- sapply(colnames(my_df), function(cn) {
   sprintf(
          ifelse(cn == rownames(my_df), green.f("%s"), red.f("%s")),
          my_df[,cn]
          )
    })
my_df2 <- data.frame(my_df2)
rownames(my_df2) <- rownames(my_df)
formattable(my_df2)
```

Explanation: I cannot find a way to put the `ifelse` inside of the formatter. Therefore, I create a character vector with `%s` as a placeholder and fill it out with values from the column using sprintf. Then, I combine the vectors to a matrix using `sapply`, turn it into a data frame, add row names and presto.

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to color the background of the cell instead of the text and is it possible to not color the row of suspicious?

Comment: Yes, there is, take a look at the vignettes of the formattable package for examples.